# Java - how to quickly convert variable integer -> float?

Tags: java, variables, converters

I am newbie in Java and just trying to convert a variable according to math operation. Let's have following scheme:

```
int var_result;
if(addition) {
  var_result = number1+number2; // number1, number2 => integers
}
else if(division){
  var_result = (float) number1 / number2;
  // and here is the problem - I don't know, how to convert "var_result" from integer to float
}

...just print var result ...
```

Is there any quick way, how to convert the **var_result** variable in this case? The easiest way in this example would be don't convert it and just use `float var_result_float`, but I don't want to solve it this way...

Thanks

Comment: *"I don't want to solve it this way..."*  Why not?  (AKA "Why should we care what you want?")

Comment: What do you mean by `Is there any quick way,`? This will take about 20 ns, is that not quick enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int var_result;` is already declared. You can't expect to store a float in it, without losing precision.

When you perform type-casting, the variable is temporarily treated as another type for the purpose of evaluation of an expression but that does not change what it actually is.

An int remains an int. You should go with `float var_result_float` to store a float.

Answer (score 3):

`int var_result` is an `int` variable.
If you need a `float` use a `float var_result`

> I don't want to solve it this way...

Well...This is the **only** way.

Comment: Well, not only way, it's possible to use Object reference and Float or Integer instance. Or to create FloatOrInt class, with appropriate getters and setters and exceptions thrown. Sure, this isn't generally useful or sane, but it's possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store an `int` or `float` in a variable you can use a `double` to store all possible values.

IMHO Don't use a `float` if you can possibly avoid it as its precision is fairly poor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change type of variable, but you can get what you want this way:

```
Object var_result; 
if(addition) { 
  var_result = new Integer(number1+number2); // number1, number2 => integers 
} 
else if(division){ 
  var_result = new Float( (float) number1 /  (float) number2); 
}
```

Of course to use the number, you have to test the type with instanceof and do cast to Float or Integer as needed, so this is very clumsy.